# Why is My One to Many Query So Slow with Linq to Entities?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have two ViewModels:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<PartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class PartViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm querying the database like this, to get the listing of Products, along with the associated Parts:

```
var prods = _context.Products.Select(pr => new ProductViewModel
{
    Id = pr.Id,
    Name = pr.Name,
    Parts = pr.Parts.Select(prt => new PartViewModel
    {
        Id = prt.Id,
        Name = prt.Name
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

There are ~8800 records in the Product table and only 1 record in the Part table. This query takes nearly 4 minutes to run. When I remove the Parts list like so:

```
var prods = _context.Products.Select(pr => new ProductViewModel
    {
        Id = pr.Id,
        Name = pr.Name
    }).ToList();
```

...it takes around 4 seconds.

Here are my table definitions in the database, created via Code First EF (I made sure to show indexes, being this may be an indexing issue:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Part](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Part] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Part]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Part_Product_ProductId] FOREIGN KEY([ProductId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Part] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Part_Product_ProductId]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Part_ProductId] ON [dbo].[Part]
(
    [ProductId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Part] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Part] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Finally, here are the two code first entities:

```
[Table("Product")]
public partial class Product
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Product()
    {
        Parts = new HashSet<Part>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}

[Table("Part")]
public class Part
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }    

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

If you need more code or information, let me know. Can you see what I'm doing wrong? What will get the data back in quicker fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Parts = pr.Parts.Select(prt => new PartViewModel
{
    Id = prt.Id,
    Name = prt.Name

}).ToList();
```

Here is the problem, for each product in `Products` you are materializing the list of items at `Parts`, that means 8800 queries to the table `Parts`.

IF you change the type of `Parts` in `ProductViewModel` to `IEnumerable<PartViewModel>` you can do:

```
Parts = pr.Parts.Select(prt => new PartViewModel
{
    Id = prt.Id,
    Name = prt.Name

});
```

That will solve the problem.

Comment: Can you show me what the code would look like when I "remove the ToList"?

Comment: Done, is just to remove the ToList().

Comment: That gives me the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PartViewModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PartViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit rusty with Linq, and what if you do the cast as the error tells you?

Comment: Sorry!! I misreaded totally the code, I was looking at Product, not at ProductViewModel. Can you replace List<Product> with IEnumerable<Product> in your class? It should make no harm as you will enumerate items at it and will be totally compatible with linq.

Comment: I did it like this and got back data in very quick fashion: var prods = _context.Products.Select(pr => new ProductViewModel
{
 Id = pr.Id,
 Name = pr.Name,
 Parts = pr.Parts.Select(prt => new PartViewModel
 {
  Id = prt.Id,
  Name = prt.Name
 })  as List<PartViewModel>
}).ToList();

Can you add that to your answer and I'll select it as an answer and delete this comment?

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy I'm not sure that is correct to do "as List<PartViewModel>"... I would recommend to change the Parts property on ProductViewModel to IEnumerable<PartViewModel>

Comment: I will do that. Thank you.

Comment: This is the answer. Never `ToList` an EF query until you absolutely have to

Answer (score 0):

Separate the queries.

```
var prods = _context.Products.Select(pr => new ProductViewModel
    {
        Id = pr.Id,
        Name = pr.Name
    }).ToList();

    var parts = _context.Parts.Select(prt => new PartViewModel
    {
        Id = prt.Id,
    ProductId = prt.ProductId,
        Name = prt.Name
    }).ToList();


prods.ForEach( pr => pr.Parts = parts.Where(prt=> prt.ProductId == pr.Id).ToList())
```

Comment: This is terribly inefficient

Comment: Why do this when a single query to the DB will do it a lot better?

Comment: It is much more efficient than 8000 subqueries to the database @Gusman. 
I can not think of a way to do it in a single query.

Comment: Read my answer, there you can see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove ToList() call but then you are left with IQueryable type. Easiest way to deal with that is to use tool like AutoMapper and map it to ProductViewModel directly in your query. So code would look something like this:

```
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;

var parts = _context.Parts
                .Include(part => part.Whatever)
                .OrderByDescending(part => part.Whatever)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ProjectTo<PartsListViewModel>()
```

Now that you selected all the parts that you need, you can actually execute query by calling:

```
parts.ToList();
```

So the general idea is to filter all the things you want and then use call like ToList() or Count() to actualy execute the query.

Also, you can optimize your query a bit if you add AsNoTracking() call. That will disable change tracking, so any change you make to your model object wont be saved. Be careful not to call it if you need to change value in database, but for read only scenario it is good to include that call as it will prevent accidental data change and run faster.

Find more about automapper at: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions.

Comment: If you read the query you will see each Product has their Parts differentiated, how will this work as it returns a single instance of parts?

Comment: This will return Iqueryable<PartsListViewModel> type, so a list of parts. Actually the first query doesn't return anything as at that point it is a query waiting to be executed. Only when you call some method on it, like List(), will it execute.

Comment: When the final query is executed through ToList the inner query will be also materialized, Linq is smart enough to project that into a simple join.